# Gazebo ignores URDF velocity and effort limits

Tags: ros, gazebo, joint, urdf, limits

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I am trying to set up a robot description file in urdf that includes "revolute" joints and simulate it in gazebo worlds. I am putting force to my simulated joint by running:

rosservice call gazebo/apply_joint_effort

and providing as argument the joint name, effort and duration.
I have also set the limits in effort and velocity in the urdf file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="expjoint">
    <link name="expbody">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" /> 
      <mass value="100.0" />
      <inertia  ixx="1" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="1"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1" />
    </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.6" rpy="0 0 0" />
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="1.0" radius="0.12"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0.6" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <cylinder length="1.0" radius="0.12"/>
      </geometry>
    </collision>
    </link>
    <link name="exparm">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" /> 
                <mass value="10" />
                <inertia  ixx="1" ixy="0.0"  ixz="0.0"  iyy="1"  iyz="0.0"  izz="1" />
        </inertial>
        <visual>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.1" rpy="0 1.57 0" />
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="1" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
        </visual>
    <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0.1" rpy="0 1.57 0" />
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="1" radius="0.02"/>
            </geometry>
    </collision>
    </link>
    <joint name="expjoint" type="revolute">
                <dynamics damping="0.0" friction="0.0"/>
        <axis xyz="0 1 0" />
        <limit effort="0.0001" velocity="0.0001" lower="-2.2" upper="1.7"/>
        <safety_controller  k_velocity="10" k_position="10" />
            <parent link="expbody"/>
            <child link="exparm"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0.17 1"/>
    </joint>
</robot>
```

**The problem is that the limits in velocity and effort are not applied when i apply the effort through the service call.** Any force and any velocity are possible, depending on the effort that is applied. Suprisingly, only the upper and lower limit of the joint seem to work.

Does anybody know what could be the cause of this?

p.s. i am launching gazebo_worlds through the empty_world.launch file.

I would be grateful if anybody could help!

Panagiotis Papadakis

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11063/gazebo-ignores-urdf-velocity-and-effort-limits/) by [Panagiotis](https://answers.ros.org/users/1014/panagiotis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2011-08-30

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's an explanation on the effort and velocity safety limits [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controller_manager/safety_limits). As far as I know, these safety limits are only taken into account if you use the [pr2_controller_manager](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_controller_manager/) as a Gazebo controller plugin (don't be fooled by the name, the controller manager is also very useful for non-PR2 robots). If you write your own controller, you can of course also write it such that it respects those limits.

Now that I think about it, it would be illogical for `apply_joint_effort` to respect those limits: they represent *desired* limits on effort and velocity that you don't want the controller to exceed. They are not *physical* limits on the joints. The service `apply_joint_effort` simulates the effect of some "external" subject other than the controller taking the joint and twisting it.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-08-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9